# LEFT JOIN query with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I did a lot of research and read some of the similar questions and answers, but still have no clue how to write the EF Core code to create the following SQL server query. Can someone help. I have seen tutorials explaining how to join 2 tables with LEFT JOIN, but couldn't find any that includes 3 or more tables.

```
SELECT std.DocID, std.ServiceCode, 
    CASE std.Description
        WHEN 'Car Wash' 
        THEN 'Misc' 
        ELSE std.Description 
    END AS 'Description', 
    std.StandardRate, std.StandardHours,
    det.ParticipantCount, det.TotalHours, det.TotalFees
FROM StandardServices std 
INNER JOIN Sorted srt 
    ON std.ServiceCode = srt.ServiceCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ServiceDetails det
    ON det.ParentRecordUNID='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND det.ServiceTypeUNID=std.DocID
WHERE std.IsDeleted='N' AND std.TopService = 'Y' 
ORDER BY srt.SortOrder
```

Following is what came close to the above (I have replaced some text for privacy concerns, so may not exactly match). But for some reasons, it selects all of the columns than what is mentioned. Also, it adds a (SELECT 1) at the end.

```
    var results=await (from sso in context.StandardServices
                       join mos in context.Sorted on sso.ServiceCode equals mos.ServiceCode
                       join mad in context.ServiceDetails
                       on new { key1 = sso.DocID, key2 = parentId } equals new { key1 = (Guid)mad.ServiceTypeUnid, key2 = mad.ParentRecordUnid }
                                                      into jointable
                         where sso.IsDeleted == "N" && sso.TopService =="Y" 
                         orderby mos.SortOrder
                         from mad1 in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new ServiceRowDetails()
                         {
                             DocID = mad1.DocID,
                             ParentRecordUnid = mad1.ParentRecordUnid,
                             ServiceTypeUnid = sso.DocID,
                             ServiceType = sso.Description,
                             ParticipantCount = mad1.ParticipantCount ?? 0,
                             StandardFees = sso.StandardRate ?? 0,
                             StandardHours = sso.StandardHours ?? 0,
                             TotalFees = mad1.TotalFees ?? 0,
                             TotalHours = mad1.TotalHours ?? 0
                         }).ToListAsync();
```

**UPDATE:** Made changes as @IvanStoev commented below and it worked just fine.

```
    var results=await (from sso in context.StandardServices
                           join mos in context.Sorted on sso.ServiceCode equals mos.ServiceCode
                           join mad in context.ServiceDetails
                           on new { key1 = sso.DocID, key2 = parentId } equals new { key1 = (Guid)mad.ServiceTypeUnid, key2 = mad.ParentRecordUnid }
                                                          into jointable
 from mad1 in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where sso.IsDeleted == "N" && sso.TopService =="Y" 
                             orderby mos.SortOrder

                             select new ServiceRowDetails()
                             {
                                 DocID = mad1.DocID,
                                 ParentRecordUnid = mad1.ParentRecordUnid,
                                 ServiceTypeUnid = sso.DocID,
                                 ServiceType = sso.Description,
                                 ParticipantCount = mad1.ParticipantCount ?? 0,
                                 StandardFees = sso.StandardRate ?? 0,
                                 StandardHours = sso.StandardHours ?? 0,
                                 TotalFees = mad1.TotalFees ?? 0,
                                 TotalHours = mad1.TotalHours ?? 0
                             }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If you really care about generated SQL, you shouldn't be using ORM, and in particular EF Core at it's current stage. EF Core is known to perform the so called [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) for the LINQ query parts that it cannot translate. In that regard, the exact EF Core version is very important (they are constantly improving over the time), so what is yours?

Comment: If you have to do that, I think your EF classes are not very good - there should be just navigation properties between tables and you should just use `StandardServices.Include(x => x.ServiceDetails)`

Comment: Forget about EF Core, anyone know how to do this with Entity Framework. By the way, I inherited a project where some SQL tables have no relationship defined for some specific reasons.

Comment: @IvanStoev the version I am using is EF Core 2.1

Comment: Can't give you a concrete answer because you didn't post the classes used in the LINQ query, but looks like the problem is caused by your unusual left join LINQ implementation. Try moving the `from mad1 in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()` line right after the `into jointable` line (the standard LINQ left join pattern).

Comment: @IvanStoev I think what you suggested seems to be working, but I will confirm it Tomorrow. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, the query is just what I wanted after making that change you suggested. Thanks again.